# How to create subdomains ' apache2 '?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

i saw this [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=151769) . But it seems outdated as mine httpd.conf is empty and it looks some sort of divided configuration under "/etc/apache2 ".(I am on ubuntu 10 server)

and i can use same ip ? right ?

**I have files like**

```
apache2.conf  
envvars     
magic           
mods-enabled  
sites-available
conf.d        
httpd.conf  
mods-available  
ports.conf    
sites-enabled
```

**Q: and i can use same ip ? right ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can use the same IP address.

You need to do a little research into VirtualHosts.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost>
    ServerName  somedomain.com
    DocumentRoot    /srv/domains/somedomain.com/htdocs
    ErrorLog    /srv/domains/somedomain.com/logs/error_log
    CustomLog   /srv/domains/somedomain.com/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost>
    ServerName  otherdomain.com
    DocumentRoot    /srv/domains/otherdomain.com/htdocs
    ErrorLog    /srv/domains/otherdomain.com/logs/error_log
    CustomLog   /srv/domains/otherdomain.com/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Personally I break up the individual domains into pieces and place them in conf.d (all .conf files should be loaded in that folder by default)

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/installation/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#configure-apache-for-named-based-virtual-hosting) is about setting up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu Server 10.04.